# Crash while typecasting a pointer - C

Tags: c

C-Beginner Question:

I have the following code that crashes at line `unsigned long rdwValue = *((unsigned long*)pParamPtr);`. I am cross compiling the code for a MIPS32 target on a fedora machine using GCC

```
unsigned char* pParamPtr = GetNvParamRamAddress(ParameterId, swIndex);

if (0 != pParamPtr)
{
    unsigned long rdwValue = *((unsigned long*)pParamPtr);// CRASHES
}
```

But if I change the line inside the `if` to

```
rdwValue = *(pParamPtr);
```

this works.

Am I doing something against the rules with this typecasting?

What I need is to get a four bytes [unsigned long is 4 bytes] from address starting at `pParamPtr` into rdwValue.

Is it `memcpy` the way to go?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What platform is this running on?

One likely reason is alignment restrictions being violated, if the returned pointer is odd and the platform doesn' support reading `unsigned long`s from odd addresses this would fail.

**UPDATE** According to a comment the OP is running this on MIPS, which certainly has alignment restrictions.

As a minor stylistic point, your outer pair of parenthesis aren't needed, it could be just:

```
unsigned long rdwValue = *(unsigned long *) pParamPtr;
```

It might be easiest to read the bytes one by one, that also gives you a chance to handle endianness explicitly. Assuming little-endian (and at least 32-bits of `int` precision):

```
unsigned long rwdValue = pParamPtr[0] | (pParamPtr[1] << 8) | (pParamPtr[2] << 16) | (pParamPtr[3] << 24);
```

Comment: I am cross compiling the code for a MIPS32 target on a fedora machine using GCC. If am not allowed to do this can you suggest a work around?

Comment: As unwind said, when you access memory you need to use addresses that are aligned to the size of the storage type you use. See e.g. [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/MIPS_Assembly/MIPS_Instructions) and [here](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/Mips/addr.html)